# Edited Plugin not Loading new version

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I have edited a GUI in QT of a plugin and made changes to the code. Have exported the correct ui.py files and files paths within the python elements of the plugin, look to be correct.

However, I cannot load the new version, it remains the same as the old one with NO changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Plugin Reloader plugin.

Comment: Thanks, i restarted qgis and reloaded using plugin reloaded and it worked